# Change Color of AppCompatButton programmatically

Tags: android

Support library 22.1 introduced a new AppCompatButton which should be tint aware and a new DrawableCompat class to set the tint of a drawable.

I just thought that it now should be easy to create colored buttons and change the button color programmatically.

I create a button in code, get the background drawable of it and try to tint it with the new DrawableCompat class and then I set it back to the button.

```
AppCompatButton btn = new AppCompatButton(context);

Drawable tintDr = DrawableCompat.wrap(btn.getBackground());

DrawableCompat.setTint(tintDr, Color.BLUE);

btn.setBackground(tintDr);
```

The result is that on Android 5.x the button is blue but ripple effect gets lost and clicking the button looks quite strange.
On Android < 5.0 the button is grey.

How can I tint a button programmatically on all Android versions?

Comment: 1) Don't change background, change backgroundTint. It will change the color and keep the default button style. 2) backgroundTint (API 21) doesn't seem to be working with AppCompatButton, at least on my end.